# How to call python function(tensorflow) from C#

Tags: python, tensorflow, ironpython

My environment is windows10, python3.5.I used tensorflow to train a neural network and wrote an interface function to return my results, and now I want to call the function in C # project. I know there is a plugin in C # like Ironpython, but it looks like it only supports python2.7, and I try to add my third party library to the path, but the result failed. I do not know how to solve this problem...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import multiarray from numpy.core
```

Comment: do you have a solution yet?